# Pure virtual function

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

I know in C++, 
`virtual double f()=0;` is a pure virtual function, 
what about 
`virtual void f() 
{return 0.0};`?
Is this a pure virtual function?

Comment: No, `virtual void f() {return 0.0};` is not a pure virtual function.

Comment: That would fail to compile (void function cannot return a value)

Comment: Additionally, it'll earn at least a strong reprimand from your compiler, for your silly notion of attempting to return 0.0 from a function that's declared to return a `void`.

Comment: `f()=0` does not mean that the function returns zero when called.  It means that the function has no implementation at all.

Answer (score 2):

No. A function is pure virtual if and only if it is declared with `= 0`.

Note that it is possible to provide a definition for a pure function, but you have to do that in two steps:

```
struct X
{
    virtual double f() = 0;  // pure, X is abstract
};

double X::f() { return 0; }  // definition
```

Usage:

```
X x;  // error, X is abstract

struct Y : X
{
    double f() override
    {
        return X::f();  // OK, calls pure virtual function
    }
};

Y y;  // OK, Y overrides X::f
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure virtual function is function marked with `=0`. It implicitly makes the class abstract. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Derived classes must to override inherited pure virtual functions or it will be abstract too.

Comment: I just begin to write about implementation of pure virtual but @Kerrek SB alredy done.